# Dynamic Time Warping - Why do we need the lowest cost path

Tags: classification, normalization, distance, pattern-recognition, dynamic-time-warping

My question is connected with the famous data mining algorithm Dynamic Time Warping also known as only DTW. According to wikipedia, the distance between two sequences is the (i-th,j-th) element of the DTW matrix. But I see in the reseach papers that for classification we need two find the lowest cost path/warping path, which is the sum of all cells in this path (not sure). Can't we use only the value of the DTW[i, j]? Also, I see that many people are dividing the distance by a constant and say that this is a normalization. Why do they do this?

Answer (score 3):

By construction, DTW[i, j] contains the minimum cumulative distance of all possible alignments. Other matrix elements are intermediate results with no immediate use.

Normalization is required to compare alignments of different lengths. E.g., without normalization, the cumulative distance between two short timeseries would be more likely lower than the cumulative distance between two long ones, even though the latter actually match better. Whether it is possible to meaningfully normalize or not, and the correct normalization "constant", depend on the actual DTW recursion used.